Are there any special considerations when replacing a thermostat?
I have an existing newer thermostat for a mini-split systems that I want to replace. Here's a picture of the wiring.

And here's one showing what the manual says:

I'd like to replace it with a Nest, if possible.
The issue I have is that it seems like the air doesn't turn off after the room temperature has reached the set point. As such, I feel like I have to monitor the system all the time. Essentially, I only turn it on when I need the air and I can't "program" the system to come on and go off at certain times.

What is the model # of the thermostat and what type of heat/cool/whatever are you trying to control (as much information as you can provide - make, model, etc.)?

People think 12 volts is safe and it is.  You can still short/blow something out with the power still on.  Turn off the power first.

Mini-splits do their own thing, so you can't really replace it with a standard thermostat
Your system appears to be a mini-split type unit.  While inexpensive and efficient, the primary tradeoff is that they require a much smarter outdoor unit to achieve that efficiency.  As a result, the indoor control on a mini-split is essentially a "dumb terminal" that talks to the outdoor unit via a proprietary protocol that is not supported by third-party thermostats.
So, your system will need a specific LG wired controller to replace the existing one if it doesn't work.  There are a few third-party systems (most notably, Mysa's mini-split control product) that can control minisplits using an IR-blaster type techinque, but I'm not personally familiar with how well or poorly they work.

The primary consideration is voltage; your schematic indicates a 12V system and the documentation for Nest thermostats says it works with 20-30V systems; they're designed for standard North American HVAC systems that use 24V AC.
Note that some (older, especially) NA HVAC use high voltage (line voltage, ~120V AC) and Nest are not compatible with those either.
Nest's official compatibility checker walks laypersons through checking wiring for compatibility with their thermostat models, mostly by looking at the wire colors at the thermostat terminals.
If you enter your wire colors at the compatibility checker link above, it indicates "inconclusive" and that you'd need to contact support and send in your picture.
